# Where Linux sets its kernel and user-space segment selector values?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, archlinux

I have verified that in Linux the following values are assigned to the kernel and user-space segments respectively:

```
__KERNEL_CS = 0x60
__KERNEL_DS = 0x68
__USER_CS = 0x73
__USER_DS = 0x7b
```

After examining the Linux source, I wasn't able to identify where Linux sets the above values into these segments. Actually, I've found the following assigments (/arch/x86/include/asm/segment.h):

```
#define __KERNEL_CS (GDT_ENTRY_KERNEL_CS * 8)           /* 2*8 = 0x10 */
#define __KERNEL_DS (GDT_ENTRY_KERNEL_DS * 8)           /* 3*8 = 0x18 */
#define __USER_DS   (GDT_ENTRY_DEFAULT_USER_DS* 8 + 3)  /* (5*8)+3 = 0x2B */
#define __USER_CS   (GDT_ENTRY_DEFAULT_USER_CS* 8 + 3)  /* (6*8)+3 = 0x33 */
```

Any help towards the understanding of this will be appreciated.

Comment: My mistake..I was looking the X86_64 defines instead of the X86_32 ones..now is shorted.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ egrep -srl '(KERNEL|USER)_[CD]S' arch/x86/kernel
```

I'd look at `entry_32.S`.